# Change the background color of a toggle button when the toggle button is checked

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to change the background color of a toggle button when the toggle button is checked and vice versa.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What do you have? what have you tried? You should try to put more effort in you questions, otherwise no one will bother to answer you...

Comment: i am new to WPF.I have a togglebutton on my window. when user do check it the back color has to change and if it is unchecked then the default color should apply.How can i achive this in WPF. pls help

Answer (score 61):

```
<ToggleButton Content="toggle">
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"                  
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter> 
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```

Nearly the same as Klaus ones, but using "TemplateBinding" instead of "TargetName".
With the TemplateBinding, the ControlTemplate use the BorderBrush and Background from the ToggleButtons DefaultStyle. So the Trigger can set the ToggleButtons Background and with the Border this one will also be shown.

Comment: Works. Using your "<Setter Property="Template">" part helped me see the IsChecked background. Thanks

Comment: To add the button border in benba solution:  
  
'BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"'

Comment: This solution still works in .NET 4.7.2 and VS Studio 2019

Comment: In 2023, with WPF this solution is not working.

Answer (score 10):

The best simple way to acheive this (and without any Blend and overriding 50 lines of XAML ;) is this way, i.e. using triggers :

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <ToggleButton x:Name="tg" Height="20" Width="80">
        <ToggleButton.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>

            </Style>
        </ToggleButton.Style>
    </ToggleButton>
</Grid>
```

Try this in the first place before going any further and see if it suit your needs

Comment: This does not work in WPF V4.0.  It momentarily changes the color of the button when pressed, but then the button reverts to the built-in style. There's some sort of "animation" of the background that is taking over. It's very lovely, and impossible to override.

Comment: I like this solution because it keeps the underlying button ControlTemplate intact and overrides only what is special about toggle buttons.  I suspect @Cheeso has problems because the default button template does something "clever" whereas I am using a custom one that is not clever at all.

Comment: This did not work for me, I'm using VS 2017 & WPF 4.5.

Comment: TooggleButton Template must be overridden to achieve this - using WPF4.5

Answer (score 9):

Check [this solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/b12f7f82-d8da-428b-8a36-ca14ed36866a):

```
<Grid>
<Grid.Resources>
  <Style x:Key="ToggleButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
          <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="border" Padding="5,5,5,5" CornerRadius="5,5,5,5" Background="#FFBFACAC" BorderBrush="#FF000000" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"/>
          </Border>
          <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
              <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFC31010"/>
            </Trigger>
          </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</Grid.Resources>

<ToggleButton Content="ToggleButton" Margin="25" Width="90" Height="45" Style="{StaticResource ToggleButtonStyle1}"/>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 8):

Do you have Expression Blend? It can be done easily by right-clicking on the ToggleButton and Select "Edit Template" then "Edit a copy...". From the template go to the "States" Tab and select the "Checked" state. Reset the background color, differing from the base state and your done.

See sample:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#F3F3F3" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#EBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#DDDDDD" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#CDCDCD" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBorder" Color="#FF707070"/>
    <Style x:Key="ToggleButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBorder}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" RenderDefaulted="{TemplateBinding Button.IsDefaulted}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="White">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates" ei:ExtendedVisualStateManager.UseFluidLayout="True">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Chrome">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
                            <ei:ExtendedVisualStateManager/>
                        </VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="RenderDefaulted" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="RenderPressed" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ToggleButton Content="ToggleButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="36" Margin="116,131,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="122" Background="White" Style="{DynamicResource ToggleButtonStyle}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I doubt you actually tested this, OP wants to change the Background color of the ToggleButton when it's checked, your sample does not manage to do that.

Comment: The instructions worked perfectly for me with VS 2017. Granted I probably have double the code I really need, it was simple for me as a WPF noob.

Answer (score 3):

Came across this issue in blend 2019, following will solve the issue.

```
<Style x:Key="ToggleButtonNormalStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
<Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Background}"/>
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Border}"/>
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
<Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
<Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Button.IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Background}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Border}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Background}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Border}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Background}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Border}"/>
                    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Once default style created adding following code will get the default selection behaviour when button checked and unchecked.

```
<Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Background}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Border}"/>
                </Trigger>
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to handle the the Checked and Unchecked events in XAML like this:

```
<ToggleButton Checked="HandleChecked" Unchecked="HandleUnchecked" ... />
```

and in the code-behind:

```
    private void HandleChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ToggleButton toggle = sender as ToggleButton;
        toggle.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
    }

    private void HandleUnchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ToggleButton toggle = sender as ToggleButton;
        toggle.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  if ((sender as ToggleButton).IsChecked ?? false)
          {                 
              btnArchive.Background = (SolidColorBrush)(new
                  BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#b8860b")); 
        }
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation, not everyone may get it what you are doing here.