# Changing Button Color using Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to change background color of Button using ListBox. I have 3 ListBoxItems for 3 colors ( green, yellow and red). I am not sure how to do this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3">
  <ToggleButton Height="50" Content="Change!" Name="button">
   </ToggleButton>
    <Popup  IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=button}"   StaysOpen="False">
     <Border Background="LightYellow">
       <ListBox>
        <ListBoxItem>Green</ListBoxItem>
         <ListBoxItem>Yellow</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Red</ListBoxItem>
      </ListBox>    
    </Border>
  </Popup>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses no code-behind. It binds with the listbox. It shows better without the popup as you will have to remove focus from the button to see the change with the popup.

```
   <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3">
        <ToggleButton  Height="50" Content="Change!" Name="button">
            <ToggleButton.Background>
                <Binding ElementName="lb" Path="SelectedItem.Content" />
            </ToggleButton.Background>
        </ToggleButton>
        <Popup  IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=button}"   StaysOpen="False">
            <Border Background="LightYellow">
                <ListBox Name="lb" >
                    <ListBoxItem>Green</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem>Yellow</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem>Red</ListBoxItem>
                </ListBox>
            </Border>
        </Popup>
    </StackPanel>
```

Remove the `<Popup  IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=button}"   StaysOpen="False">` and `</Popup>` lines which will put the listbox directly under the button. This will show the color change immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Give your ListBox a name and attach an event handler `SelectionChanged`.

```
<ToggleButton Height="50" Content="Change!" Name="button">
<ListBox x:Name="myListBx" SelectionChanged="MyListBx_OnSelectionChanged">
    <ListBoxItem>Green</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Yellow</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Red</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

Then on back end you can do something like this (Tested working)

```
private void MyListBx_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string SelectedColor = (myListBx.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem).Content.ToString();

    switch (SelectedColor)
    {
        case "Yellow":
            button.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
            break;
        case "Green":
            button.Background = Brushes.Green;
            break;
        case "Pink":
            button.Background = Brushes.Pink;
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution using a Converter. The converter will take receive the string value and then return a colour, see below.

```
public class StringToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var listItem = value as ListBoxItem;
        if (listItem != null)
        {
            var text = listItem.Content;
            switch (text)
            {
                case "Green":
                    return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                case "Yellow":
                    return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
                case "Red":
                    return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }
        }
        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You made a mistake in your xaml because you cannot directly change the background of a togglebutton. Below is how to use the converter with your actual code. Please note it will only change the background of the textblock. to make the button look better [Please see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618800/change-the-background-color-of-a-toggle-butt)

```
<StackPanel>
    <Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=button}" StaysOpen="False">
        <Border Background="LightYellow">
            <ListBox x:Name="ColorPicker">
                <ListBoxItem>Green</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Yellow</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Red</ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
        </Border>
    </Popup>
    <ToggleButton Name="button"
                  Height="50"
                  >
        <TextBlock Text="Change!" Background="{Binding Source={x:Reference ColorPicker}, Path=SelectedValue, Converter={StaticResource StringToColorConverter}}"/>
    </ToggleButton>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **SelectionChanged** event handler  in ListBox control as like below,

```
    private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var listBoxItem = ((sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as ListBoxItem);
        button.Background = (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString(listBoxItem.Content.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this with DataTrigger

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="2">
            <Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=button}"  StaysOpen="False">
                <Border Background="LightYellow">
                    <ListBox x:Name="ColorPicker" >
                        <ListBoxItem>Green</ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem>Yellow</ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem>Red</ListBoxItem>
                    </ListBox>
                </Border>
            </Popup>
            <ToggleButton Name="button"
                  Height="50">
                <TextBlock Text="Change!" >
                    <TextBlock.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ColorPicker,Path=SelectedIndex}"  Value="0">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ColorPicker,Path=SelectedItem}"  Value="1">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"></Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBlock.Style>

                </TextBlock>

            </ToggleButton>
        </StackPanel>
```