# Change button color on click event

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

On default I have set my button color as `Gainsboro`, on button click, I set it to Orange. What I am having trouble is to revert the color back on the same button click event. How can I achieve this? I am trying to do a "on off switch" kind of button. Can I ask if this method is good? Because I also need to code for conditions if button is Orange or not

xaml

```
<Button x:Name="btnWIP" Text="non WIP" BackgroundColor="Gainsboro"/>
```

code

```
public bool isWIP = false;
private void btnWIP_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    isWIP = true;
    if(isWIP == true)
    {
        btnWIP.Text = "is WIP";
        btnWIP.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#FFBE57");
    }
    else
    {
        btnWIP.BackgroundColor = Color.Gainsboro;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a comment that it seems you may be trying to reinvent the toggle button control? In which case your formatting can be achieved by the flowwing, and the `IsChecke` property is stored on the button. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618800/change-the-background-color-of-a-toggle-button-when-the-toggle-button-is-checked

Comment: You should set the `isWIP` inside your if/else block. In your code it will always be true and so never enter the else block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a logic flaw in your code. You always set `isWIP = true` before checking it, and the condition will always be true.

You could change it up like this:

```cs
public bool isWIP = false;
private void btnWIP_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    isWiP = !isWIP; // that way, you will change the value of isWIP on each click to true/false
    if(isWIP == true)
    {
        btnWIP.Text = "is WIP";
        btnWIP.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#FFBE57");
    }
    else
    {
        btnWIP.BackgroundColor = Color.Gainsboro;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of forcing the boolean on true, you should invert it. Meaning; when it's true, it will become false, when false it will become true:

So you need to write something like:

```
if(isWIP == true)
    isWIP = false;
else
    isWIP = true;
```

You can write this also shorter:

```
isWIP = !isWIP;
```

---

```
public bool isWIP = false;
private void btnWIP_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // invert the boolean
    isWIP = !isWIP;

    if(isWIP == true)
    {
        btnWIP.Text = "is WIP";
        btnWIP.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#FFBE57");
    }
    else
    {
        btnWIP.BackgroundColor = Color.Gainsboro;
    }
}
```